# Multiple Separate WHERE classes in single VIEW

Tags: sqlite, view, where-clause

I need help creating a single SELECT statement as part of a CREAT VIEW statement that contains multiple, separate filtering or grouping requirements.

I am working on an SQLite database to track usage of our local food pantry, where we have two types of visitors, “Scheduled” or “Drop-In”, visiting on different days.  One of the central tables is the “visit_log” table that tracks each visit by date, time, type of visit, and people in the household.

I’m trying to create a VIEW that summarizes that “visit_log” grouped by the visit_date, and for both number of records and  SUM of household size,  displaying the number of “Drop-Ins”, the number of “Scheduled” and the total of the two types.

Here is the “visit_log”

```
CREATE TABLE "visit_log" ("visit_date" DATE, "visit_time" TIME, "client_relation" TEXT, "household_size" INTEGER)
```

Here is a sample of the “visit_log” table’s content. (We have not started recording the visit_time yet, so those values are blank).

```
"visit_date","visit_time","client_relation","household_size"
"6/9/20","","Scheduled","1"
"6/9/20","","Scheduled","1"
"6/9/20","","Drop-In","2"
"6/9/20","","Drop-In","3"
"6/9/20","","Drop-In","8"
"6/9/20","","Drop-In","5"
"6/16/2020","","Scheduled","1"
"6/16/2020","","Scheduled","1"
"6/16/2020","","Drop-In","4"
"6/16/2020","","Drop-In","5"
"6/16/2020","","Drop-In","2"
"6/16/2020","","Drop-In","2"
"6/16/2020","","Drop-In","5"
"6/16/2020","","Drop-In","1"
```

I can create three separate VIEW, one for each type and one for the two combined.  But my goal is to have the results of these three VIEWs in one.

Here are the three VIEWs.  First is for the two client types combined.

```
CREATE VIEW "visit_summary" AS SELECT
visit_date,
COUNT (*) AS households_total,
SUM (household_size) AS individuals_total 
FROM 
"visit_log"
GROUP By visit_date
```

This yields

```
"visit_date","households_total","individuals_total"
"06/09/2020","12","44"
"06/16/2020","8","21"
"06/23/2020","7","20"
"06/30/2020","10","22"
"07/07/2020","7","18"
```

Next is the VIEW for the Drop-Ins

```
CREATE VIEW "visit_summary_dropin" AS SELECT
visit_date,
COUNT (*) AS households_dropin,
SUM (household_size) AS individuals_dropin
FROM 
"visit_log"
WHERE client_relation = "Drop-In"
GROUP By visit_date
```

This yields

```
"visit_date","households_dropin","individuals_dropin"
"06/09/2020","10","42"
"06/16/2020","6","19"
"06/23/2020","4","13"
"06/30/2020","6","12"
"07/07/2020","6","16"
```

Finally is the VIEW for the Scheduled

```
CREATE VIEW "visit_summary_scheduled" AS SELECT
visit_date,
COUNT (*) AS households_schedualed,
SUM (household_size) AS individuals_scheduled 
FROM 
"visit_log"
WHERE client_relation = "Scheduled"
GROUP By visit_date
```

This yields

```
"visit_date","households_schedualed","individuals_scheduled"
"06/09/2020","2","2"
"06/16/2020","2","2"
"06/23/2020","3","7"
"06/30/2020","4","10"
"07/07/2020","1","2"
```

What I'm hoping to create is a single VIEW that yields

```
    "visit_date","households_total","individuals_total","households_dropin","individuals_dropin","households_schedualed","individuals_scheduled"
"06/09/2020","12","44","10","42","2","2"
```

etc…

So my ultimate question, finally, is how to create a single VIEW containing something like multiple WHERE classes to define different columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
CREATE VIEW visit_summary_scheduled_all AS 
SELECT visit_date,
  COUNT(*) households_total,
  SUM(household_size) individuals_total,
  SUM(client_relation = 'Drop-In') households_dropin,
  SUM(CASE WHEN client_relation = 'Drop-In' THEN household_size END) individuals_dropin,
  SUM(client_relation = 'Scheduled') households_scheduled,
  SUM(CASE WHEN client_relation = 'Scheduled' THEN household_size END) individuals_scheduled 
FROM visit_log
GROUP By visit_date
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uNbGZo9rTid6pNaM17q2L6/3).
Results:

```
| visit_date | households_total | individuals_total | households_dropin | individuals_dropin | households_scheduled | individuals_scheduled |
| ---------- | ---------------- | ----------------- | ----------------- | ------------------ | -------------------- | --------------------- |
| 6/16/2020  | 8                | 21                | 6                 | 19                 | 2                    | 2                     |
| 6/9/20     | 6                | 20                | 4                 | 18                 | 2                    | 2                     |
```